# I want two rows to next to each other HTML table

Tags: html

I am working on an HTML newsletter and I am trying to get the coded black row that say Bar, to be attached to the row beneath containing images. The problem is that my black row does not contain separate white spaces and it does not connect to that row. Here is my code for this segment.

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="5" width="100%">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td width="190" bgcolor="#000000">Bar</td>

            <td width="190" bgcolor="#000000">Bar</td>

            <td width="190" bgcolor="#000000">Bar</td>

        <tr>

            <td width="190" height="100" >
                <img src="/Users/Desktop/90snostalgia.jpg" alt="" width="190" height="130"/>
            </td>


            <td width="190" height="100">
                <img src="/Users/Desktop/90snostalgia.jpg" alt="" width="190" height="130"/>
            </td>

            <td width="190" height="100" >
                <img src="/Users/Desktop/90snostalgia.jpg" alt="" width="190" height="130"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: do you need to avoid margins in the bottom of the row above?

Comment: Yes, I want to keep the horizontal space between <td>, but avoid the margins between the <tr> rows.

Comment: Then you should set cellspacing to zero, and use style's margin settings for every td

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding something like this to your CSS should get you there, if I understand you correctly.

```
* { color:#fff } /** not needed. just couldn't see your fonts **/
table { width:572px }
tr td { border-left:1px solid white; padding:5px }
tr td:first-child { border-left: none }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the cellspacing on your table tag... Cellspacing="0"...

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
```

Answer (score 0):

it is because of the cellspacing. Try to invert the cellspacing and cellpadding like this :

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I am trying to have the images an equal length off the side of the 600 width table container. If I make cellpadding="0" my furthest left image is touching the border and everything else has space in-between.

Comment: if you want that the image touches the border, that set cellpadding="0", but then set all width's to 200px